# Numeric field null value transformed to Zero Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to insert a row in a table in Oracle. One of the fields in Numeric and I want it to be null but when it is inserted in my database I see a Zero "0". This happends only in few machines not in all. What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your client program is displaying `NULL` values as zero.

Try this:

```
 SELECT your_numeric_column
 FROM   your_table
 WHERE  your_numeric_column IS NULL
```

If you see a bunch of zeros, you'll know that it is the client program on those machines that is displaying NULLs as zeros.